# playing video's sound on mouseover

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, shopify

hello i have a problem with a script I have a video and I want to play the sound of the video on mouse over and mute it on  mouse out
I tried this script but doesn't work 
he return for me this error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'muted' of undefined

```js
<script>
    window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById("sos").onmouseover = function() {mouseOver()};
   document.getElementById("sos").onmouseout = function() {mouseOut()};
        function mouseOver() {
          document.getElementById("sos").video.muted = "false";
        };
    function mouseOut() {
          document.getElementById("sos").video.muted = "true";
    };}
  </script>
```

```html
<video id="sos" width="100%" height="100%" autoplay muted loop src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0329/9960/4283/files/Bird_jingle_compress.mp4?v=1591684742"></video>
```

thanks

Comment: You should not need to add `video` as an index. Try `document.getElementById("sos").muted = "false";`

Comment: now there is no error but doesn't make the sound effect :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following example.

```js
function toggleMute(el) {
  el.muted = !(el.muted);
}

window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("sos").onmouseover = function() {
    toggleMute(this);
  };
  document.getElementById("sos").onmouseout = function() {
    toggleMute(this)
  };
}
```

```html
<video id="sos" width="100%" height="100%" autoplay muted loop src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0329/9960/4283/files/Bird_jingle_compress.mp4?v=1591684742"></video>
```

I do not hear the Video's audio, but when I show controls, I can see it changes from Muted to Volume Full. Unsure if the video has an audio track, so I would test with another video maybe.

**Alternate**

You asked about using MouseOver / MouseOut events with Mobile Browsers. This simply does not exist as there is no "mouse" and therefore, no mouse movement to track.

jQuery Mobile offers this:

> The jQuery Mobile `"vmouseover"` event handler simulates the "onmouseover" event handler on mobile devices.
>
> This plugin extends jQuery's built-in method. If jQuery Mobile is not loaded, calling the `.vmouseover()` method may not fail directly, as the method still exists. However, the expected behavior will not occur.

**Example**

```js
$(function() {
  function toggleMute(el) {
    el.muted = !(el.muted);
  }
  $(document).on("vmouseover mouseover", "#sos", function(e) {
    console.log(e.type);
    toggleMute(this);
  });
  $(document).on("vmouseout mouseout", "#sos", function(e) {
    console.log(e.type);
    toggleMute(this);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>

<video id="sos" width="100%" height="100%" autoplay muted loop src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0329/9960/4283/files/Bird_jingle_compress.mp4?v=1591684742"></video>
```

As you can see, both events get triggered in a normal browser. When testing with Mobile Browser, only the virtual mouse events should be triggered. Results may vary and this library has not been updated since 2014.

Comment: thanks but I think th on mouse functions doesn't work on mobile how I can make this for mobile ??

Comment: @SKANDORI Mobile browsers do not have a MouseOver / MouseOut event as there is no "mouse". You can look at TouchPunch or other libraries that help map that type of event from Mobile browser to JS.

Comment: I know it's just I don't have any idea how I can do this can you help please ?

Comment: @SKANDORI No, I am not going to do it for you. It's not really a realistic request in the first place. Since you're using native JS, you may consider switching to jQuery or jQuery Mobile. The latter, offers: https://api.jquerymobile.com/vmouseover/

Comment: I don't know lot about jquery you can't help also in jquery  ?